# How to make active_admin member_action accept GET as well as POST requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, activeadmin

I want my active_admin member action to accept GET as well as POST requests. What should I do?

This doesn't work:

`member_action :stats, :method => [:get, :post] do`

And if we don't specify method, it assumes it to be :get (viewed source and the default is set as :get)

How do I do it in a DRY manner? I could write the same function twice:

`member_action :stats, :method => :post do`

`member_action :stats, :method => :get do`

but I would feel really bad if I had to do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer : you can't. When using member_action, you are just creatin an instance of AA:ControllerAction which only supports one verb.

But there is hope :), you can just write your member action with the verb which has more meaning (does it have side effect ? POST, should it be bookmarkable ? GET ) and then open your routes.rb and add something like this :

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :your_resource do
    get 'stats', :on => :member
    post 'stats', :on => :member
  end
end
```

Comment: Or override logic provided by router model to support symbol arrays ) https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/router.rb#L51

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Just a minor variation. I define the member_action with method GET in Active admin, therefore the GET route gets generated. I just need to specify the POST route in the routes.rb file. We can get rid of the first one, else rake routes shows 2 GET routes.